# Error "dynamic_cast class unconditional" in XCTestCase with core data

Tags: core-data, swift, xcode6

I would like to do some unit tests with Core Data in my swift app, and this is the first time I use Core Data.

To ease my tests I just copied the code generated for the Core Data variables (managedObjectModel, managedObjectContext, ...) from the regular AppDelegate to my test file.

I just want to do something pretty simple and which worked in my app :
`var user: User = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: context) as User`

The thing is when I launch my test I got this error : `swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional` with `EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)` but when I continue program execution my test finish well with all I am waiting for.

EDIT : At first I prefixed my class name with my project name `MyApp.User`, but after I saw that if I put `@objc(User)`, I didn't need the prefix, so I took of the prefix.

Where does this error come from ? Why is my test OK at the end ?